# C preprocessor push_macro/pop_macro and forcing expansion in between

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a macro, call it `FOO`, that I am trying to override only in my header file. I am trying push_macro/pop_macro to do it in Visual Studio. The problem is because the macro I am trying to override is used as part of another macro `BAR`, the replacement `FOO` isn't used. For example:

```
#define FOO(x) printf("You're in the regular FOO. %s", x);

// These next few lines would be in an include file.
#pragma push_macro("FOO")
#undef FOO
#define FOO(x) printf("You're in the replacement FOO. %s", x);
#define BAR(x) FOO(x)
#pragma pop_macro("FOO")

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    BAR("test");
    return 0;
}
```

That code prints:

> You're in the regular FOO. test

The code is much more complicated than this, I kept it simple for the example. There are multiple replacement FOO in the include file so I can't just put the contents of FOO in BAR.

Is there a way to force expansion of FOO in the include file before restoring the macro via pop_macro? Can I do a selective extra pass or something like that?

Comment: This would be amazingly useful, and I wish for the same feature, but I don't think any such thing exists.

Comment: @MooingDuck: you are right, it does not exist.  I have seen people do this (and been guilty of it myself in my younger days): `#define OLD_FOO FOO   #undef FOO  #define FOO(x) ...  #define FOO OLD_FOO   #undef OLD_FOO`.  Of course it does not work as expected, but I agree it would have been nice if it could.

Comment: does the header file have to come after the original FOO?

Comment: Seems like an XY-problem; why would you want to do this?  The simple "solution" is just `#define BAR(x) printf("You're in the replacement FOO. %s", x)`  No messing about with redefining FOO or push_macro/pop_macro

Answer (score 0):

I have found a partial solution (or rather just bad workaround). You can fill the macro stack with alternating definitions of original and replacement FOO. And then each call to BAR would first pop one FOO, use FOO, and pop another FOO. So each call to BAR consumes two elements from the FOO stack. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to restore the elements, as you can't call `#define` inside another `#define`. So in this workaround, `BAR` can only be used as many times as corresponds to the size of the `FOO` stack you hardcode:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define FOO(x) printf("You're in the regular FOO. %s", x);
#define FOO_MY(x) printf("You're in the replacement FOO. %s", x);

// These next few lines would be in an include file.
#define FOO_CALL(x) FOO(x)
#pragma push_macro("FOO_CALL")
#undef FOO_CALL
#define FOO_CALL(x) FOO_MY(x)
#pragma push_macro("FOO_CALL")
#undef FOO_CALL
#define FOO_CALL(x) FOO(x)
#pragma push_macro("FOO_CALL")
#undef FOO_CALL
#define FOO_CALL(x) FOO_MY(x)
#pragma push_macro("FOO_CALL")
#undef FOO_CALL
#define FOO_CALL(x) FOO(x)
#pragma push_macro("FOO_CALL")
#undef FOO_CALL
#define FOO_CALL(x) FOO_MY(x)
#pragma push_macro("FOO_CALL")
#undef FOO_CALL
#define FOO_CALL(x) FOO(x)

#define BAR(x) \
        _Pragma("pop_macro(\"FOO_CALL\")") \
        FOO_CALL(x) \
        _Pragma("pop_macro(\"FOO_CALL\")")

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FOO("test\n");
    BAR("test\n");
    FOO("test\n");
    BAR("test\n");
    FOO("test\n");
    BAR("test\n");
    FOO("test\n");
    BAR("test\n");
    FOO("test\n");
    BAR("test\n");
    FOO("test\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
You're in the regular FOO. test
You're in the replacement FOO. test
You're in the regular FOO. test
You're in the replacement FOO. test
You're in the regular FOO. test
You're in the replacement FOO. test
You're in the regular FOO. test
You're in the regular FOO. test
You're in the regular FOO. test
You're in the regular FOO. test
You're in the regular FOO. test
```